# Removing Selected Values from ListBox

Tags: c#, arraylist, listbox

I am getting collection of values from COL_name and adding each value to The listbox named as **lstDisplay** ,and the values are getting added.At the same time i need to remove the same values in COl_name from the **lstAvailable** ListBox,but the values are onli gettin added in **lstDispaly**,its not getting deleted from the anotherList box  namde as **lstAvailable**.

```
            foreach (string drr in COl_name)
            {
                lstDispaly.Items.Add(drr);
                lstAvailable.Items.Remove(drr);
            }
```

Thank you..

Comment: Could you please introduce some more context? The code segment that you shared looks fine to me. The problem might lie elsewhere.

Comment: @ByteBlast :ya while debugging in lstDisplay the value is getting added but not getting removed in LstAvailable.

Answer (score 0):

It's means, you have no drr object in lstAvailable. 
Try to do like this:

```
foreach (string drr in COl_name)
            {
                lstDispaly.Items.Add(drr);
                lstAvailable.Items.RemoveAt(COL_name.IndexOf(drr));
            }
```

Or you can try to override Equals() method in you class

Comment: But the best way, to override Equals() method in class witch collection you have. If you'll do this, .Remove method will work fine

Comment: add to you post class wich in your collection, and I will help you

Comment: sorry i couldnt get you ?? could you pleasse tell in detail../

Answer (score 0):

[`ListBox.ObjectCollection.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove.aspx) uses `Equals` to determine if two objects are equal. So if your object (what type is it?) does not override `Equals` menaingfully you would compare references. If both objects are not the same reference they are not considered equal then.

Another reason could be that the `ListBox` contains objects that are not strings but you are "removing" strings. Then you could use `RemoveAt`:

```
var obj = lstAvailable.Items.Cast<object>()
   .Select((obj, index) => new{ obj, index })
   .FirstOrDefault(x => (x.obj == null ? "" : x.obj.ToString()) == drr);
if(obj != null)
    lstAvailable.Items.RemoveAt(obj.index);
```

Comment: null values are coming.